# Does xgboost "fit" function allow to continue training?

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost

I am wondering if my K-Fold implementation is correct:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kf = KFold(n_splits=numFolds, shuffle=False, random_state=7)
sales_prediction_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(
                    silent=False,
                    learning_rate=0.03,
                    n_estimators=10000,
                    max_depth=4,
                    # sub_sample=0.8,
                    gamma=1,
                    colsample_bytree=0.8,
                    n_jobs=30
                )

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train):
     X_tr, X_te = X_train.iloc[train_index], X_train.iloc[test_index]
     y_tr, y_te = y_train.iloc[train_index], y_train.iloc[test_index]
     eval_set = [(X_tr, y_tr), (X_te, y_te)]
     sales_prediction_model.fit(X_tr, y_tr, verbose=False,
          early_stopping_rounds=15,eval_set=eval_set, eval_metric="mae")
```

Is the fit function continues the training, or starts again from scratch?

Thanks for your help.

(The xgboost documentations only states : *"Fit gradient boosting model"*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement incremental training for xgboost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079853/how-can-i-implement-incremental-training-for-xgboost)

Comment: Are you sure you want to continue training? In cross-validation one typically wants to train an independent model on each iteration, i.e. "from scratch"