# Incremental Learning with multi-output XGB

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, xgboost

I am trying to perform incremental learning with XGB, wrapped with Sklearn's MultiOutputRegressor to obtain multi-class regression:

```
# For instance
# X = np.zeros((1, 8)
# y = np.zeros((1, 32)

multi_model = MultiOutputRegressor(
            xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror')
            ).fit(X, y)
```

However, if I repeatedly call *multimodel.fit(X_new, y_new)* it creates a new model, without performing incremental learning.

I tried with *"partial_fit()"* and specifying *"multi_model"* within the *.fit* function but both solutions are not supported.

**How could I achieve incremental learning with multi-class XGB?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving and reusing your previous saved model and passing it to fit(xgb_model = 'trained_xgb_model.model')? [Refer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079853/how-can-i-implement-incremental-training-for-xgboost)

Comment: I can't; if you check Sklearn's documentation for MultiOutputRegressor (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html), the .fit method can only accept X and y.